# Recognizing haskell types

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I'm having some difficulties in understanding the types in haskell. Let's consider the following functions and look at their types.

```
reduce f s [] = s
reduce f s (x:xs) = f x (reduce f s xs)

for m n f s = if m>n then s else for (m+1) n f ( f m s )

comp f g x y = f x (g x y)

iter 0 f s = s
iter n f s = iter (n-1) f (f s)
```

We'd have something like:

```
reduce :: (t1 -> t -> t) -> t -> [t1] -> t
for :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> (a -> t -> t) -> t -> t
comp :: (t -> t2 -> t3) -> (t -> t1 -> t2) -> t -> t1 -> t3
iter :: (Num t) => t -> (t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1
```

What I don't clearly understand is that in  reduce function f takes two parameters, and in for function f again takes two parameters. All I can see is  that it takes only one. Well if it would be something like that:

```
for m n f s = if m>n then s else for (m+1) n f m n
```

It would be more obvious and easy to recognize that f indeed takes two parameters.

I'm wondering if there exist some ways or method to deduce the types for functions in haskell. In addition to these examples I'd ask for some different examples, so that I can overcome that hardship.

EDIT: In my case function definitions are given, I am just trying to infer their types

Comment: You're tackling this wrong. Always _start_ from the types and how you're planning to use the final function, and then think about the implementation. — About "in `for` function `f` again takes two parameters. All I can see is that it takes only one": how much clearer than `( f m s )` can it get? You're very literally feeding the function two arguments by hand. Or what do you mean?

Comment: yeah it seems so but, when it comes `f ( f m s )` it confuses me

Comment: `f ( f m s )` is part of `for (m+1) n f ( f m s )`. the first `f` is applied to the recursive `for` call. Always put types in your top-level definitions

Comment: As I edited in my case function definitions are given, I am just trying to infer their types

Comment: Well, you may well do that as an excercise, but really inferring types is a job you can leave to ghci. I'd suggest you try instead to implement `singleFor :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> a -> (a -> t) -> t -> t` (hint: you'll run into trouble because the looped function lacks a second argument). That'd be a much better practise excercise.

Comment: The `else` part of `for` is a recursive call to `for`, with four arguments: `m + 1`, `n`, `f`, and `f m s`. It's pretty clear from this that `f` takes two parameters. In your "easy" example, `f` is never used so it can be any type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where you're making a thought mistake is in even considering `f ( f m s )`. That is *not* a subexpression of the `for` definition: recall that function application is parsed from the left. So

```
for (m+1) n f ( f m s )
 ≡ (for (m+1)) n f ( f m s )
 ≡ (for (m+1) n) f ( f m s )
 ≡ (for (m+1) n f) ( f m s )
 ≇ (for (m+1) n ) (f ( f m s ))
 ≇ for (m+1) (n f ( f m s ))
 ≇ for ((m+1) n f ( f m s ))
```

The last inequality is probably most obvious, because you'd be applying the function `(m+1)` to three arguments... that sure looks very unlikely.

If you need any "mental parenthesising" for understanding the function, it's normally best to put them around each function argument:

```
for (m+1) n f ( f m s )
 ≡ for (m+1) 
       (n)
       (f)
       (f m s)
```

and, if that helps you because it looks more like what you'd have in mainstream languages, you can also *uncurry* everything:

```
 ≅ for ( m+1, n, f, f(m,s) )
```

(though you'd better forget about that one quickly)

---

By the way: if you see a function applied to only one argument, it doesn't mean the function type has *only* one argument. In fact, the main strength of Haskell's curried syntax is that you can easily do *partial application*: e.g.

> Prelude> :t take
>   take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
>   Prelude> :t take 3
>   take 3 :: [a] -> [a]
>   Prelude> map (take 3) ["looooong", "even loonger", "terribly long"]
>   ["loo","eve","ter"]

You see I've only applied `take` to one argument, the other one is automatically taken from the list by `map`.

Another example, with operator sections,

> Prelude> :t (+)
>   (+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
>   Prelude> :t (+ 1)
>   (+ 1) :: Num a => a -> a
>   Prelude> map (+ 1) [4,5,6]
>   [5,6,7]

Comment: That's partial application. Partial evaluation is a compile-time optimization technique.

Comment: @Carl: Thanks. Though, I wouldn't say it's an optimisation, it's a very general technique with lots of applications. But what I described really isn't partial evaluation, so you're right to point this out.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `f` in the following definition is quite easy to infer

```
for m n f s = if m>n then s else for (m+1) n f ( f m s )
```

This could be rewritten (for clearity) as

```
for m n f s 
    | m>n       = s
    | otherwise = for (m+1) n f ( f m s )
```

1. `for (m+1) n f (f m s)` is a call of `for`,
2. which means `f m s` needs has the same type as `s`,
3. this requires `f` to have type `t1 -> t -> t`
   (`t1` for `m`, and `t` for `s`)